# Live streaming a web page with video/audio elements

Tags: linux, audio, video, streaming, headless

i am trying to do a website/browser livestream on a headless linux, but couldn't find a good solution yet.

Headful example: In OBS Studio you can add a Browser Source of a web page that includes video/audio and stream this content live out.

So what i basically want is like a headless version of this.

I tried a bit with phantomjs and chrome-headless, but these tools are not supporting video or audio outputs in headless mode. If there is an alternative that can output a web page stream with video/audio would be awesome.

This output can then piped to ffmpeg and launch a rtmp stream :)

Thanks!